# java send email using annotations and aop

Tags: java, annotations, aop

I want to send emails only if they have an annotation in the method, using spring AOP. But how do I get the values in objects using annotation. For example, I have the following method. By using AOP, I can track when placeOrder is called. But how do I get ordernumber, user email address and items ordered from AOP code.

```
@SendEmail()
public void placeOrder(){
    //ordernumber
    //user email address
    //items ordered
}
```

Is it possible to have objects in annotations and the methods can set the objects. For example

```
@SendEmail(order=<order instance>, user=<user instance>, items=<list of item instance>)
public void placeOrder(){
    Order order;
    User user;
    List<Item> items;
}
```

Comment: Well it depends on the implementation of the @SendMail annotation.Take a look at the example of RequestForEnhancement in this [link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html). Can you add details on @SendMail?

Comment: Yes, i can add details. I looked at the link, but all the values are string. I would like to be able to access other members and instance variables of the instance or somehow pass the required values to the annotation But not sure if there is a way to do that

Answer (score 0):

in an annotation you can use only primitives, String, Class, enums, annotations, and arrays of the preceding types. You can obtain the same behaviour using the AOP advice. If you wanna to access to the method objects args or obtain the advise target you can write an advisor like this:

```
@Aspect
public class AOPSampleAdvice {
.....
    @AfterReturning("execution(* *..YorServiceInterface.placeOrder(..))")
    public void afterReturning(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
                /*Use this if the order is passed in the method signature*/
        //Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
        //Order order = (Order) args[0];
                /**/
        Object target = joinPoint.getTarget();
                List<Item> items = ((YorServiceInterface) target).getItems();
        User user = ((YorServiceInterface) target).getUser();
                //Your business
    }
```

Every time the placeOrder method is called when this method return start this advise. You can use:

```
@Before
@AfterReturning
@AfterThrowing
@After (finally)
@Around
```

To register this advise in your applicationContext.xml write this:

```
<!-- enable aop -->
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

<bean id="adviseAspect" class="com.foo.acme.AOPSampleAdvice"/>
```